# NodeJS http request handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, applescript, after-effects

In my project I am working with 2 async methods. The first method opens an Applescript which opens an After Effects project and loads a jsx file (to adjust items in the After Effects project). The second method renders the adjusted After Effects project and renders it to an .mp4 file.

The problem with the first method is that it can open After Effects well, but it can open only one instance of After Effects, because After Effects only allows to open 1 After Effects project at a time.

In case there are multiple HTTP request to the code, After Effects will throw an error. Because it has to open multiple After Effects project the same time, which is not allowed.

I am looking for a way to queue HTTP requests for this method, so that After Effects can be opened once, and after a couple of seconds the second request is performed and After Effects will be opened again, again, and again... Is there a way of doing this in NodeJS? Because my code won't do this, and I can't find a solution on the net/stackoverflow.

```
exports.renderProject = function (req, res) {

async.series([
        function (callback) {
            callback();
        },
        function (callback) {

            var template = req.body[0].template; //project to render (.aep file)

            //OSX editproject
            var editProject = executablepathOSX + " " + template + " " + template + ".jsx" + " " + guid /*retValVacancyList[0].animation.template*/

            var sys = require('sys');
            var exec = require('child_process').exec;
            var child;

            // executes 'edit project'
            child = exec(editProject, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout);
                sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr);
                if (error !== null) {
                    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
                }
                callback();
            });

        },
        function (callback) {

            var renderProject = shellscript + "renderMp4.sh " + guid + ".aep " + guid + ".mp4"//guid + ".avi" //animation.template .avi name(guid)

            var sys = require('sys');
            var exec = require('child_process').exec;
            var child;

            // executes 'render project'
            child = exec(renderProject, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout);
                sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr);
                if (error !== null) {
                    console.log('exec error: ' + error);
                }
                callback();
            });
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`async.queue`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue):

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var aequeue = async.queue(function(template, callback) {
  var editProject = executablepathOSX + ' ' + template + ' ' + template + '.jsx' + ' ' + guid /*retValVacancyList[0].animation.template*/

  // executes 'edit project'
  exec(editProject, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    callback(error);
  });
}, 1);

async.series([
  function (callback) {
      callback();
  },
  function (callback) {
    aequeue.push(req.body[0].template, callback);
  },
  function (callback) {
    var renderProject = shellscript + "renderMp4.sh " + guid + ".aep " + guid + ".mp4"//guid + ".avi" //animation.template .avi name(guid)

    // executes 'render project'
    exec(renderProject, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      callback(error);
    });
 }
```

Comment: I putted the aequeue to the 'global' part of the js route. Now it works great! Thanks for your help!